# Mensaje [Object Object] al imprimir en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

estoy obteniendo los permisos de un rol seleccionado pero donde debería estar el nombre del permiso, solo me muestra un mensaje:

> [object Object]

Les muestro en imagen:

[image]

como se ve en la imagen, el rol seleccionado (NuevoRol) tiene 2 permisos, pero en vez de aparecer el nombre del permiso, aparece 2 veces [object object]

me podrian ayudar por favor, adjunto codigo:

CONTROLLER

```js
    public function viewEvents($id)
    {
        $event = Role::where('id', $id)->first();
        $event->getAllPermissions();
        return json_encode($event);
    }
```

AJAX

```js
$(document).on('click', '.viewEvents', function() {


  $('#view_event_alert').html('');
  var id_rol = $(this).data("id");
  var view_html = '';

  var url = "{{url('viewRoles')}}/" + id_rol;

  $.get(url, function(r) {
    var edata = $.parseJSON(r);
    if (edata.id > 0) {
      $('#view_roles_modal').modal('show');

      $('#view_event_alert').html('');

      $('#view_roles_title').text(edata.name);

      $('#view_roles_permisos').text(edata.permissions);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: que se supone que están en una tabla relacionada, entonces en la relacionada solo me muestra los ID, pero no los nombres, y segun la documentación de spatie con ese código me daba todo, pero no me lo da :c

Answer (score 5):

> Aclarando que esto tiene mas que ver con JavaScript que con Laravel en si mismo o el package que estás usando.

Sin tener a la mano un escenario idéntico al tuyo, te explicaré de una forma un tanto genérica lo que esta ocurriendo:

Asumamos que tenemos un objeto de este modo:

```
let misObjetos = {
  valor1: "valor1",
  valor2: "valor2",
  valor3: "valor3"
}
```

El cual si imprimo por consola me arroja lo siguiente:

```
console.log(misObjetos)
```

Resultado:

```
[object Object] {
  valor1: "valor1",
  valor2: "valor2",
  valor3: "valor3"
}
```

Sin embargo si ahora deseamos imprimir sus valores en un `div` HTML y procedo de este modo:

```
  <div id="contenido"></div>


let divsito = document.getElementById("contenido")
divsito.innerHTML = misObjetos
```

Obtendré un mensaje como este:

```
[object Object]
```

No logra mostrar los valores de manera adecuada por:

- Es un objeto que necesita ser *parseado*

Usaremos en cambio `JSON.stringify` que me ayuda en resumidas cuentas a y cito a la [doc de Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify)

> El método JSON.stringify() convierte un objeto o valor de JavaScript en una cadena de texto JSON, opcionalmente reemplaza valores si se indica una función de reemplazo, o si se especifican las propiedades mediante un array de reemplazo.

```
let divsito = document.getElementById("contenido")
divsito.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(misObjetos)
```

Con un resultado como el siguiente:

```
{"valor1":"valor1","valor2":"valor2","valor3":"valor3"}
```

Puedes comprobar los tipos de datos que se regresan en cada uno de los dos puntos expuestos, realiza lo siguiente:

Resultados:

```
console.log(typeof misObjetos) //object
console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(misObjetos)) //string
```

De hecho si imprimes en consola ambos valores en el mismo orden que están arriba se verían de este modo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como puedes observar al ser la segunda una *string* por eso puedes imprimirlo de manera correcta en el `div`

**Referencias**

- [innerHTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)
- [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DOMString)
- [JSONstringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify)

Lo último sería que adaptes tu código en JQuery a lo mencionado

Comment: Ouch es un tema complejo entonces, gracais por explicarme y tomarte el tiempo de escribir todo

Answer (score -2):

Este me funciono por *jquery*. Estoy consumiendo una **api rest** y ese objeto lo estoy mostrando en una alerta.

```
          {},
          function(data) {
            if(data){
                alert(data)     
                    console.log(data.nombre_completo);
                    var nombre1 = data.nombre_completo;
                    alert(nombre1)  
            }else{
                alert("error")
            }
         });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]